# Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':app:processDebugResources' property 'sourceOutputDir' during up-to-date check

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I'm working on Windows 10 and just starting with react-native. from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

One of the first steps to get started is to run: react-native run-android. But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':app:processDebugResources' property 'sourceOutputDir' during up-to-date check.

  > Could not read path 'C:\Users\Kourosh\Desktop\React Native\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\android\arch\lifecycle\livedata\core'.

Comment: Try to run ‘react-native run-android’ this always happens with me and I just re run the application

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this happens after changing your `styles.xml` in `android/app/src/main/res/values`, run this:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

[Source (Github issue comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10367#issuecomment-308153481)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the cache does fix it. But only once, if you stop the project and re run it, you ll end up with same error again.

Doing following fixes it for me,

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
react-native start --reset-cache
npm clean cache --force
```

Next, open two different terminals run

```
react-native start
```

in one and in second run

```
react-native run-android
```

Hope it'll work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have an Ionic 4 project, into your project folder, go to platforms/android and run ./gradlew clean.

```
cd platforms/android
./gradlew clean
ionic cordova run android -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that being logged into a domain account on Win caused these problems. I logged in as a local (machine) account and they went away. The clue was that it smelled like a permissions issue.